# import a file in a folder python

Tags: python, flask

I want to import a file from a folder in my replit discord.py project. I’m using the same project to do a website , with flask. This is the structure

```
project ——|—— main.py
          |
          |—— static ——|—— Templates —— index.html
                        |
                        |—— flask_.py
```

I’m using a function who keep alive the bot using uptime robot. Before, I didn’t need a website. The flask app just print in a website output I’m alive. But now, I want to create a full website with flask using HTML. The HTML isn’t a problem. The problem is that, in the structure, you can see that **flask_.py** is in the folder static and the **main.py** file isn’t. Because the function to keep alive the bot is in flask_.py, I can’t import it like that `from flask_ import keep_alive`. I don’t know how to import it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start from the root directory of the project:

```
from static.flask_ import keep_alive
```

But why do you have have dynamic code in a folder named `static`? I suggest moving the `flask_.py` folder to the root of the project then you can use the import you already have.

Side note: in python, we typically use underscores to separate words in names. Ending a filename with an underscore is unusual.

Comment: Because in the flask_.py file, I’m also hosting a website

Comment: static is generally used for things like jquery, images, icons, html templates -- things whose content do not change, and need to be served by the webserver or hosted elsewhere. Answer is correct that it is odd to have a .py file in that dir.

Comment: @W1L74680 Like jorf.brunning says, a `static` folder usually contains files that a web server will return in a response as-is. These can be static HTML files, JavaScript, CSS, or images. These are files that are just copied straight into the response stream. The server does not execute any of this code. With that said, it is a convention and not strictly enforced by the HTTP server or by Python. But using `static` for other purposes will confuse other people.

Comment: Ok. I will still use it for other files for my project thanks!